# Modal form not positioning in the middle of display text area of blogger

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

The floating modal form TOC is not positioning in the center of the display text area of blogger. The position is varying among computers. In some computers browser it is showing within the display text area of blogger. But the same is not in another computers.

I need the modal form should be at center of the post-body.

Pagelink: https://easygrammartips.blogspot.com/p/countable-nouns.html

```js
// This function toggles the visibility of the card body.
function toggleCardBody(cardBodyId, arrowIconId) {
  var cardBody = document.getElementById(cardBodyId);
  var arrowIcon = document.getElementById(arrowIconId);

  // Check if the card body is currently visible.
  if (cardBody.style.display === "none") {
    // If the card body is not visible, show it and change the arrow icon to a down arrow.
    cardBody.style.display = "block";
    arrowIcon.classList.remove("fa-chevron-right");
    arrowIcon.classList.add("fa-chevron-down");
  } else {
    // If the card body is visible, hide it and change the arrow icon to a right arrow.
    cardBody.style.display = "none";
    arrowIcon.classList.remove("fa-chevron-down");
    arrowIcon.classList.add("fa-chevron-right");
  }
}

// This function resets the visibility of the card body to hidden.
function resetCardBody(cardBodyId, arrowIconId) {
  var cardBody = document.getElementById(cardBodyId);
  var arrowIcon = document.getElementById(arrowIconId);

  // Hide the card body and change the arrow icon to a right arrow.
  cardBody.style.display = "none";
  arrowIcon.classList.remove("fa-chevron-down");
  arrowIcon.classList.add("fa-chevron-right");
}

// This function shows the floating ToC wrapper.
function showFloatingTocWrapper() {
  var floatingTocWrapper = document.getElementById("floatingTocWrapper");
  floatingTocWrapper.style.display = "block";
  floatingTocWrapper.style.top = "50px"; // Adjust the top value as needed
}

// This function hides the floating ToC wrapper.
function hideFloatingTocWrapper() {
  var floatingTocWrapper = document.getElementById("floatingTocWrapper");
  floatingTocWrapper.style.display = "none";
}

// This function listens for the scroll event and shows or hides the floating ToC wrapper as needed.
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var tocWrapper = document.getElementById("tocWrapper");
  var floatingTocWrapper = document.getElementById("floatingTocWrapper");
  var rect = tocWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Check if the ToC wrapper is below the fold.
  if (rect.bottom <= 0) {
    // If the ToC wrapper is below the fold, show the floating ToC wrapper.
    showFloatingTocWrapper();
  } else if (rect.bottom > 0) {
    // If the ToC wrapper is not below the fold, hide the floating ToC wrapper.
    hideFloatingTocWrapper();
  }
});
```

```css
/* Additional styles for the floating modal form */

.floating-toc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 770px;
  /* Adjust the max-width value as needed */
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 9999;
  max-height: 300px;
  /* Adjust the max-height value as needed */
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: none;
  /* Initially hidden */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="text-black">
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div id="tocWrapper" onmouseleave="resetCardBody('cardBody1', 'arrowIcon1')">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" onclick="toggleCardBody('cardBody1', 'arrowIcon1')">
            <h5>Table of Contents<i id="arrowIcon1" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body" id="cardBody1" style="display:none">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#List-01">What is Countable Noun?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-02">What are the key aspects of Countable Noun?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-03">Examples of Countable Noun</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-04">Usage of 'a lot of', 'many' with plural Countable Nouns</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-05">Usage of 'some', 'any' with plural Countable Nouns</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-06">Usage of 'a few', 'few' with plural Countable Nouns</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-07">Exercise on Countable Nouns</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text-black">
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div id="floatingTocWrapper" class="floating-toc" onmouseleave="resetCardBody('cardBody2', 'arrowIcon2')">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" onclick="toggleCardBody('cardBody2', 'arrowIcon2')">
            <h5>Table of Contents<i id="arrowIcon2" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body" id="cardBody2" style="display:none">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#List-01">What is Countable Noun?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-02">What are the key aspects of Countable Noun?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-03">Examples of Countable Noun</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-04">Usage of 'a lot of', 'many' with plural Countable Nouns</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-05">Usage of 'some', 'any' with plural Countable Nouns</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-06">Usage of 'a few', 'few' with plural Countable Nouns</a></li>
              <li><a href="#List-07">Exercise on Countable Nouns</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text-black" id="List-01">
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: rgba(0, 82, 212, 0.1);">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="question">
        <h2 style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #0052D4, #4364F7, #6FB1FC); color: white;">What is Countable Noun?</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="bigfont"><span>A</span> countable noun is a noun that can be counted. It has a singular and a plural form. The singular form can use the determiner "a" or "an". If you want to ask about the quantity of a countable noun, you ask "How many?" combined with
          the plural countable noun.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text-black" id="List-02">
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: rgba(0, 82, 212, 0.1);">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="question">
        <h2 style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #0052D4, #4364F7, #6FB1FC); color: white;">What are the key aspects of Countable Noun?</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12" id="answer">
        <ol>
          <li><b>They can be counted.</b> This means that you can use numbers to refer to them, such as "one dog," "two cats," and "three trees."</li>
          <li><b>They have a singular and a plural form.</b> The singular form is used when referring to one of the noun, while the plural form is used when referring to more than one of the noun. For example, the singular form of "dog" is "dog," while the
            plural form is "dogs."</li>
          <li><b>They can be used with determiners.</b> Determiners are words that come before nouns to tell us how many or which one of something we are talking about. Some common determiners that can be used with countable nouns include "a," "an," "some,"
            "many," "few," and "all."</li>
          <li><b>They can be used with verbs.</b> The verb form that is used with a countable noun should agree with the number of the noun. For example, "The dog barks" (singular verb) and "The dogs bark" (plural verb).</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```